# Tableau - Multiple Line on Same Graph

Tags: tableau-api

I have a simple line graph with DATE on the X-Axis and PRODUCT on the Y-AXIS.

I have created a Parameter that gives the user ability to choose which PRODUCT to display on the line graph. However, I would like the user to be able to see more then one product on the graph, not just one. I would like them to be able to see multiple products on the same graph if they desire.

Right now there is only one line graph, even if they select multiple products. I would like them to all be displayed separately.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Parameters are single select only. Can you use just regular filters?

Comment: Multiple selections are not possible using parameters, Also where are you using measure in line graph, as to get a line graph one measure is primary requirement

Comment: Sorry, I actually have a FILTER that gives the user ability to choose which PRODUCT to display on the line graph.

BUT

The actual measure references another Parameter. For example,
if ([Dimension] = 'Volumes') then ([Volumes])
elseif ([Dimension] = 'Balance') then ([Balance])
END

Comment: Can you edit the question with more explanation

Comment: What is the measure on your Y-axis? Is it s distinct count of products? Or is product your dimension for which you are applying an aggregation to some other measure (like a sum of sales or volumes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag your PRODUCT dimension from the Rows shelf to the color shelf (or detail shelf if you do not want each PRODUCT to be a differently colored line). Then add the desired measure to your rows shelf (like 'Number of Records' if thats what you want to measure). Then ensure that your graph type (options are above the color shelf) is still 'Line.'

This should ensure that the aggregate against your measure on your Y axis is calculated for each distinct PRODUCT dimension.

Additionally, on your X-axis you can use DATEPART() (for non-unique months, days, hours, etc) or DATETRUNC() (for unique months, days, hours, etc) to ensure that your aggregation against each measure is applied and graphed for each PRODUCT dimension accordingly (ie: you could have a node for each line plotted with the sum of every month, day, hour, etc).

Comment: Sweet, thank you! I just dragged my Product measure to the color lines and it worked.